# Using apex Code How to create Listview on Sobject, Having standard and custom fields

Tags: salesforce

Anyone having idea about how to create Custom ListView on Standard Sobject, that can have both standard as well as custom fields.

Please share your knowledge.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the tab for the custom object in you are in Classic salesforce click the "Create New View" link next to the list view droplist if in Lightning click the Cog to the right top of the UI then click the "New" menu option.  Select the Standard and Custom fields that you want to appear in the list view, I believe up to 10 fields, and the criteria for the view and who can see the listview, then save.

You can create this via code using the metadata API. You would have to download one of the wsdl files, use the wsld to Apex generator to create a wrapper for it and use that to create a soap envelope with the request.  It might be easier to use https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi where he did the work already, see this posth